# What area to use for the lift/drag forces

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm trying to model the orbit of a satellite around the earth at 500km above the surface. I have the nose cone radius and the surface area of the wings so should I be using the cone radius for the drag and the wing area for the lift or wing area for both of them?

Comment: Hello! This question really belongs on http://space.stackexchange.com/. At 500 km, lift is negligible and drag is present, but so it's a spacecraft specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using equations with $C_L$ and $C_D$ you need a (single) reference area, $S_{ref}$:

$$L = q_\infty S_{ref} C_L$$
$$D = q_\infty S_{ref} C_D$$

For aircraft this is generally the wing planform area. However, for a satellite, wings aren't going to be of much use, so the area upon which molecules will be impinging (such as the nose cone or cross sectional area normal to the flow) would be a more useful choice. Your coefficients will vary depending on which area you choose. Note that it really doesn't make sense to try to model the "lift" of a satellite.

On that note, satellites, especially at altitudes as high as 500 km, are essentially ballistic, so the [ballistic coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_coefficient) is perhaps a better choice:

$$ BC = \frac{M}{C_d A} $$

Here $A$ is the cross sectional area of your object, but for all intents and purposes it's very similar to $S_{ref}$. We can substitute it back into the drag equation to get something useful for satellites:

$$ D = \frac{q_\infty M}{BC} $$